# How can I create a sequence table that I can use to give me a sequence value?

Tags: sql-server

I have been using this sequence tables:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[TestId1]
    AS BIGINT
    START WITH 301
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO CACHE;
```

Now I realize "SEQUENCE" is not allowed on SQL Azure and I need to make a sequence table from a normal table somehow

Does anyone have any ideas on an alternative? Note that when getting a sequence value I am always getting this from inside of a stored procedure.

**Update:**

Using the proposed method and calling like this:

```
DECLARE @outvalue INT; EXEC [dbo].[usp_NextLimitSequence] 'Order', 99999, @outvalue; 
Select @outvalue;
```

Gives me Null

Comment: The simplest alternative is an `identity` column. It is not an exact replacement but will gave you the desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks but I had a lot of reasons for not going the identity column route. One being that I need a string for the sequence number. First I get an integer from the seq then convert it to a string. Well at least that's what I was doing until I tried to deploy to SQL Azure :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With using a table with an identity column, you may have a table with a lot of records which I believe is overkill.  I have used this table/proc combo for years, that is until MS SQL 2012.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SequenceTable]
(
[SequenceName] [varchar] (10) NOT NULL,
[Value] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SequenceTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Sequence] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([SequenceName])
GO

create procedure [dbo].[usp_NextLimitSequence]
(
  @sequenceName varchar(10),
  @limit int,
  @value int out
)
as 
begin

  begin transaction

    update [SequenceTable]
    set [Value] = case when [Value] >= @limit then 0 else [Value] + 1 END,
        @value = case when [Value] >= @limit then 0 else [Value] + 1 END
    where SequenceName = @sequenceName;

    if ( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 ) begin
      insert into [dbo].[SequenceTable] ( SequenceName, Value )
      values ( @sequenceName, 1 );
      SET @value = 1;
    end;

  commit work

end;
```

EDIT:  Here is a more streamlined proc without the upper limit parameter

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_NextLimitSequence]
(
  @sequenceName varchar(10),
  @value int out
)
as 
begin

  begin transaction

    update [SequenceTable]
    set [Value] = [Value] + 1,
        @value = [Value] + 1
    where SequenceName = @sequenceName;

    if ( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 ) begin
      insert into [dbo].[SequenceTable] ( SequenceName, Value )
      values ( @sequenceName, 1 );
      SET @value = 1;
    end;

  commit work

end;
```

Comment: Your solution looks interesting. How would you call that from within a stored procedure ?

Comment: DECLARE @outvalue INT;  EXEC [dbo].[usp_NextLimitSequence] ('OrderNumber', 99999, @outvalue);

Comment: It could be re-write to eliminate the limit (upper limit) switch

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I was not sure what the limit was for. Can you tell me how that is used or maybe show me what the procedure would look like without it. I tried your code to declare and get the value but it complains about the "(". I then removed that but it returns a value of null as the sequence value.

Comment: I just updated the question to show what happens when I call this using the way you mentioned. Can you let me know if you have any ideas why it is outputting null. I did check and it seems to increment the value in the table okay.

Comment: I realized the word "output" is missing from the end of the call to the SP. Works great now. thanks

Comment: The limit is used to make sure the sequence number never exceeds that number.  So if it is a fast food restaurant and you don't want your order number to go higher than 100, then you would set this to be 100, as soon as the next number is 101, it will reset the sequence to 0.  I will edit the answer to show it without

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generate a series of numbers, you can generate a tally table like this:

```
WITH
    B0 AS(SELECT 1 [C] UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    B1 AS(SELECT 1 [C] FROM B0 [A] CROSS JOIN B0 [B] CROSS JOIN B0 [C] CROSS JOIN B0 [D]),
    B2 AS(SELECT 1 [C] FROM B1 [A] CROSS JOIN B1 [B] CROSS JOIN B1 [C] CROSS JOIN B1 [D]),
    Tally AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) [Id] FROM B2) 
SELECT *
FROM Tally
WHERE Id > 300
```

This will return Id's up to 65536, and if you need more, just keep adding cross joins, this for example will return numbers up to 16777216:

```
WITH
    B0 AS(SELECT 1 [C] UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    B1 AS(SELECT 1 [C] FROM B0 [A] CROSS JOIN B0 [B] CROSS JOIN B0 [C] CROSS JOIN B0 [D]),
    B2 AS(SELECT 1 [C] FROM B1 [A] CROSS JOIN B1 [B] CROSS JOIN B1 [C] CROSS JOIN B1 [D] CROSS JOIN B1 [E] CROSS JOIN B1 [F]),
    Tally AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) [Id] FROM B2) 
SELECT *
FROM Tally
WHERE Id > 300
```

Comment: What does the Tally table look like ?

Comment: It isn't an actual table, it's a common table expression that returns a table containing only one column called Id. Just run the first script above in management studio, and you'll see. (the second script will take some time, returning 16 mil rows :))